# Aligning HTML5 page layout with CSS in different browsers

Tags: css, html

Hi guys i have created an HTML5 page and used  tag. The problem is the CSS file i am using, works fine if worked on firefox but the page layout is getting all messed up on chrome and IE8. This is my simple CSS file.

```
body {
    background-color:silver;
}
header, nav, article, footer, section, aside {
    display:block;
    outline-style: groove;
    outline-color: Black;
    outline-width:thin;    
    line-height:normal;   
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
header {
    background-color:gray;
}
nav {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    min-width:120px;
    background-color:White;
}
nav h1 {
    font-size:large;
}
nav li {
    list-style-type:none;
}  
section {
     margin-left:1%;
     float:left;
     width:63%;
}
aside {
    background-color:White;
    float:right;
    width:15%;
}
article {
    /* float:right; */
    float:left;
    margin-left:4px;
    width:99%;
    background-color:White;
}
footer {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    background-color:White;
    font-size:100%;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML too.  Even better, put it in JSFiddle.net so we can help edit it for you right away.

Comment: @Fozzyuw here is the link on JSFiddle.net
http://jsfiddle.net/smaran/JeWfB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your issue is simply HTML5 support in IE8, IE7, etc.  IE9 and Chrome look the same as Firefox (I'm not sure why you mentioned Chrome was causing an issue, maybe there's something I'm not seeing?).

Anyway to fix IE, I would recommend adding HTML5 Shiv by simply adding this code in the HEAD tag.  Read about HTML5 Shiv here: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

This made IE7 and IE8 look like IE9, Chrome and FF for me.  And I believe you won't need this code either:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
       document.createElement("header");
       document.createElement("nav");
       document.createElement("article");
       document.createElement("footer");
   }
</script>
```

I believe that code is trying to support HTML5 which HTML5 Shiv will do for you.

Here's an updated Fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/JeWfB/1/

Hope that helps!
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fozzyuw that was really helpful. Yup it is working great on all. Any suggestions for me as a CSS3 beginners, which guide should i follow?

Comment: @Sam007 I would recommend the *A List Apart* (http://www.alistapart.com/) online mag for good reading on all topics on web developer/design/business.  They also produce some great short books on design.  Check out their CSS3 and HTML5 books.  Also Adaptive Web Design by Aaron Gustafson and all of Dan Cederholm's books (http://simplebits.com/#books).  The HTML5/CSS3 books from A Book Apart will help guide you to implementing them in old browsers.  I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks once again @Fozzyuw, you are a life saver

Comment: Hi @Fozzyuw i am trying to get the <nav> to be horizontal rather than vertical but the few searches i did is not working. i have updated the code in (http://jsfiddle.net/smaran/JeWfB/2/).
Also, the webpage is still displaying the rectangular boxes of <header>,<nav>, <article> even when i have used CSS to round the corners. How do i remove it?

Comment: @Sam007 Your rectangular boxes are being caused by your CSS `outline-style`, `outline-color`, `outline-width` in the selector `header, nav, article, footer, section, aside{}`.  As for the horizontal nav, I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Do you want to have the left hand nav be horz. under the header and then just a 2 column layout (instead of 3 column)?  Check out this site for horizontal navigation patterns: http://pea.rs/navigation/horizontal-links

Comment: Hi Fozzyuw, can you tell me how do i have rounded corners only on one side of the border. Like in the website you have given, the navigation on the left has only the left top and left bottom rounded.

Comment: @Sam007 In modern browsers, you simply use `border-radius`.  here's how it's supported. http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius and here's a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/GYfnn/  The downside is it was only first implemented in IE9.  Most web developers/designers subscribe to the philosophy of "it doesn't have to look the same in every browser" but sometimes it does for clients, so you'll have to fall back on older rounded corner methods.  Since it's only IE, you can do a conditional comment JavaScript solution.

Comment: Hi @Fozzyuw, I am trying to use this awesome Image Sliding Motion. It is a free HTML5 template. Here is the link http://freehtml5templates.com/fascination-html5-and-css3-template/. I downloaded the source code but i am not able to reconstruct it. I Only need the 3D Image sliding motion. So i took only that part out and have kept everything else the same, http://jsfiddle.net/smaran/rpgqD/. I have not added the CSS and JS since there are more than one, but you can find them if you download from the source code from the link i just gave you.

Comment: @Sam007 you need to post this as a new question.  Thanks!

Comment: Here is the link @Fozzyuw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917189/3d-image-transitioning-in-html5